# How to convert Scotty parameter as String

Tags: haskell, scotty

I am new to Haskell and testing some concepts with Scotty web library.

However, I can't get a simple hello world page working.
I am stuck at converting the parameter as String and apply to another function.

Here is the high-level code that is not working yet.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Web.Scotty

main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 $
  get "/" $ do
    name <- param "name" `rescue` (\_ -> return "haskell")
    greeting <- hello name
    html $ concat ["<h1>hello ", greeting, "</h1>"]

hello :: String -> String
hello s = "hello " ++ s
```

### Error Messages

```
app/Main.hs:11:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’
                     with ‘Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                             Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO’
      Expected type: Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                       Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO Char
        Actual type: String
<Omitted>
   |
11 |     greeting <- hello name
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^

app/Main.hs:12:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
<Omitted>
   |
12 |     html $ concat ["<h1>hello ", greeting, "</h1>"]
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

app/Main.hs:12:34: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Char’
<Omitted>
   |
12 |     html $ concat ["<h1>hello ", greeting, "</h1>"]
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

### Goal

The `hello` function is a stub. I would like to proof that the following mechanism work.

1. extract a parameter as String
2. apply to a `String -> String` function
3. return the result as response

### What have I read and tried

I have read the Scotty [doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.0/docs/Web-Scotty.html) and some [code examples](https://github.com/dbushenko/scotty-blog/blob/master/src/Main.hs).

I read that the `param` is of type `Parsable a => Text -> ActionM a` and `ActionM` is of type `ActionT Text IO`.

I have tried `name :: T.Text <- param "name"`, `T.unpack`, `liftIO`, etc. but no luck. I think I don't understand the types fully.

### Questions

What do the types for `param` and `ActionM` actually mean?

How can I extract the parameter as String to use with another functions?

Thank you.

Comment: What are your error messages? Focusing on those is a good way to arrive at a solution.

Comment: Also, when you say, "What does the types actually mean?", which types do you want explained? I've identified several.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Hi Michael, I have updated with the error messages. I mean the types for `param` and `ActionM`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some working code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import Web.Scotty

main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 $
  get "/" $ do
    name <- param "name" `rescue` (\_ -> return "haskell")
    let greeting = hello name
    html $ mconcat ["<h1>hello ", greeting, "</h1>"]

hello :: Text -> Text
hello s = "hello " <> s
```

Since `hello` is not in the `ActionM` monad, `let` binding can be used instead of the `<-` syntax.

`param` can be used to parse any query parameter that is of the `Parseable` type class.

`param :: Parsable a => Text -> ActionM a` means that given the text name of a parameter, `param` can give back any type you need as long as it is `Parseable`. Check [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.0/docs/Web-Scotty.html#t:Parsable) for a list of types that are available. Note that `String` is not in that list, however `Text` is. That is why in the above code I changed the `hello` function to work with `Text` instead of `String`. If you prefer to use `String`, you could unpack the parsed param like:

```
name <- T.unpack <$> param "name" `rescue` (\_ -> return "haskell")
let greeting = hello name -- where `hello :: String -> String`
```

(But then you will need to repack the result into text before using the `html` function)

The other changes that were required were replacing `concat` with `mconcat` and `++` with `<>`. These functions are accomplishing the same thing as `concat` and `++`, however are more general and work with all monoids instead of just lists.

Your last question about what the type of `ActionM` means.

Under the hood, `ActionM` is a specialized form of `ActionT`: `ActionM = ActionT Text IO`

`ActionT` represents a computation which takes place in an environment (the http request), can modify an internal state (the http response), and can result in an error. It's made using a stack of monad transformers which looks like this:

```
newtype ActionT e m a = ActionT 
  { runAM :: ExceptT (ActionError e) (ReaderT ActionEnv (StateT ScottyResponse m)) a }
```